# Slight of hand to take items faster from handy haversack

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, objects

We have a rogue in our campaign that uses slight of hand (taking a -20 penalty check) to take items (scrolls, potions, etc.) from her "handy haversack" claiming that this would reduce the action to a free action.

Is this possible?

my concerns are the following but I am not sure:
1-"handy haversack" explicitly says that it takes a movement action to take an item
2-In "sleigh of hand" there is mention about reducing a standard action to a free action (with a -20 penalty). The player argues that it is a standard action to draw a hidden weapon so should work with other light items, at the same time I think drawing a hidden weapon is not drawing an item (but could this work on wands?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

> **Retrieving any specific item from a haversack is a move action**, but it does not provoke the attacks of opportunity that retrieving a stored item usually does.

The text you are referring to about making standard actions free actions is probably this:

> ### Action
>
> Any Sleight of Hand check normally is a standard action. However, you may perform a Sleight of Hand check as a free action by taking a -20 penalty on the check.

However, this is explicitly only for *Sleight of Hand*, not **any** standard action.

#### However...

If you have a rogue in a party alongside main casters (wizard, cleric, druid), it's [probably not too much of a boost](https://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=658.0) to allow some house rules helping the rogue.